# Minify result of TailwindCSS buid, PostCSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a project using ReactJS, Webpack, TailwindCSS, and when I run the build command, the CSS file built is **TOO BIG**:

[image]

Here is my `postcss.config.js`

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss,
    require("autoprefixer"),
    require("cssnano")({
      preset: "default",
    }),
  ],
};
```

And here is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        greenLight: "#1db954",
        greyDark: "#121212",
        greyLight: "#282828",
        greyLighter: "#282828",
        backgroundLight: "rgba(40,40,40,0.4)",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        custom: ["Circular Spotify Tx T Black"],
      },
      container: {
        screens: {
          mobile: "23rem",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

And this is ```webpack.config.js
[image]

I have searched a lot, but can not figure it out! Thanks.

Comment: set `NODE_ENV=production` in a build command

Comment: Please provide your code as text instead of images, this makes it easier to copy parts to an answer

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Thanks a lot. it worked for me. But the time for recompiling when I using webpack-dev-server is too long. Do you know how to fix that? Let comment on this post, I will mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @CerebralFart sorry, I will provide code instead of images for next time. Thank you!

Comment: @LeThanhViet not sure about compilation speed, try to set your entry point as Promise callback like `entry: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(['./demo', './demo2']))` - it is called dynamic entry. Maybe it will help

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Thank you for the answer. I found a solution, low-speed bundling causes minimize and chunk when I run with webpack-dev-server. If we want to reduce the time for recompile when any changes occurred, we can use JIT mode for ```tailwind.config.js```.

Comment: @LeThanhViet You may introduce new boolean variable like `isProd`, define it and set `minimize: isProd`, so optimization will be only in production mode. Or have two different config files for production and development. But anyway this is not a scope of a question and a long topic for discussion :)